# How does the Linux kernel find the right offset to parse IP packets?

Tags: linux-kernel, ip

I've found what code parses IP (v4) packets in the [kernel source tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/ip_input.c#L398). This function, `ip_rcv`, can to a high degree of certainty detect whether a packet is correct or not, as is outlined in one of the comments:

1. Length at least the size of an ip header
2. Version of 4
3. Checksums correctly. [Speed optimisation for later, skip loopback checksums]
4. Doesn't have a bogus length

Malformed packets are simply dropped. This function seems to get a bunch of bytes that should resemble an IP packet, but what if some malicious actor would sneak an extra byte on the line? If not handled correctly, all the chunks of bytes that `ip_rcv` receives from now on will start 1 byte off and no correct IP packet can be reconstructed anymore. I assume the kernel does something smarter than to try all different byte offsets at which to start parsing an IP packet. What exactly, I'm unable to find. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't taken the time to look at the kernel code but most protocol stacks are going to work by parsing data immediately following the previous stack location and not by searching for data.

In the case of Ethernet, an Ethernet frame header is typically 14 bytes in size. It can vary but the header itself indicates the different length in the etherType field when necessary. In this example, the NIC (Network Interface Card) will receive an Ethernet frame. If the frame is destined for this NIC then the data passed from the NIC driver to the IP stack will be an Ethernet frame containing this 14-byte header followed immediately by the IP header (first nibble will be 4 if it is a version 4 IP header for instance).

Again, I didn't look at the network stack code but there are two common cases here:

1) The IP stack is told this is an Ethernet frame and only needs to parse the Ethernet frame header for its length and the very next byte must be an IP header or the data is deemed not an IP frame.

2) The IP stack is given a pointer to the beginning of the data immediately following the Ethernet frame header and the IP stack then starts parsing at that location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case, the IP stack relies on the underlying protocols to be nice. What in case of working with a ``tun`` device? Tun devices are IP-in and IP-out and nothing other than the protocol between the two tunnneling applications is protecting the IP packet's integrity. If this tunnel was built on top of an unreliable protocol, is all hope lost?

Comment: Ethernet has a CRC check on each Ethernet frame. If the received frame doesn't pass the CRC check then the frame is dropped and not sent to any underlying protocol. I would presume that any protocol you might be using should be doing the same thing. If not, then the IP checksum would hopefully find the bad data and discard it. Thus all hope is not lost, IP will retry when it doesn't receive a datagram it is expecting.